# posting array of checkboxes in a dragable UI: not getting posted

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, draggable

I am using array of checkboxes in my draggable UI, so that we can change the row order by drag and drop. When I drag the bottom entries to top I am not getting all the checked checkboxes on POST.

You can try this by moving row in inspect element.

```
<form type="post" name="chekfrm" action="index.php">
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="dconf_check[]" value="18" checked="checked" id="dconf_18" title="name"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="dconf_check[]" value="13" checked="checked" id="dconf_13" title="name"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="dconf_check[]" value="19" checked="checked" id="dconf_19" title="name"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

print_r($this->input->post("dconf_check"));

Comment: result is Array ( [0] => 18 [1] => 13 ), not getting 19 even when it is on the first row

Comment: Are you using a particular JavaScript library, like jQuery UI? I don't think there's enough information to go on here. Can you perhaps create a JS Fiddle to replicate the problem?

Comment: thanks for your comment on this,, it was the issue with Codeigniter form close. now it is working ,, I am using jQuery UI and codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was because of not closing the form in CodeIgniter (`echo form_close();`).

It was getting all checked checkboxes on POST, when it is not dragged it's place.

When I drag 4th one on the top then it will post only the checkboxes greater than or equal to 4, means we will not get the first three.